# Symfony 2 long http request locking all other actions, tried to close session lock but doesn't work?

Tags: php, symfony, session, locking

HI I am using symfony2 to do some long API calls processing
for example this call takes about 20 minutes to finish

```
$response = simplexml_load_file($apicall);
```

The problem is whenever I open any other action in another tab. It basically has to wait till the 20 minutes finish to load the result. I tried everything. I know this could be related to a session lock but I tried to close the session by using

```
$session = $this->get('session'); 
$session->save();
```

and also

```
session_write_close();
```

but nothing seems to work. I tried to close the session before the API call and after the API call. Does anyone know what should I do? It's been 2 days with this.

Comment: consider to process it as a symfony command task

Comment: I have to read about that. Can you kindly explain more?

Comment: You can write a process that you can run via CLI, or schedule via cronjob, that do some stuff. Depend what you must do with the response of the long api call. If you can turn the logic of your task to a batch processing, consider my option otherwise, check the well answer of the other user. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to `Symfony2` - this is just how `php` and sessions work. To verify this you can try to call another action in private window or another browser (to be sure it's different session) while your long api call is still pending - this request should be handled without problems (if only CPU is free).

There are several ways to fix this, but as far as I know there's no quick and easy solution. What I would suggest is starting your long api call in another process (so it doesn't lock session) and do another action which will check if your original task is finished - if so, return the result.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637182/symfony2-job-queue-or-parallel-processing) for some inspiration

Note that closing session won't help you as on new request to server a new session is started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually tried to use a different browser but it still waits till the other action finishes. So I don't know.

Comment: how about your CPU - maybe your 20 minutes api call uses 100% CPU so you can't get any response from server

Comment: I am actually using local machine at the moment. Do you think the call will consume 100% cpu . I did experience the same problem on the hosting server between a non symfony call and a symfony action. The symfony action always waits till the call is done then responds.